# Solr indexing with space and without space for same field

Tags: solr

Folks,

We have one requirement where we want to index data based in solr with and without space

Since application is already in production we donot want to add new field in schema.xml

e.g If word is like "Instititue of Excellence"

We want to index like "Instititue of Excellence" and then index with "InstititueofExcellence" by removing all the spaces in the middle.

Is there any easy way to achieve this ? ( As mentioned above we donot want to create multiple fields)

Comment: Have you tried using a ShingleFilter with outputunigrams set to true and an empty separatio char? That would index "Instituteof", "InstituteofExcellence" etc. as seperate tokens.

Comment: We are already using ShingleFilter to create multiword token like "institute of" "of excellence" etc. can we supply multiple option in shingle factory to index with space and without white space.( I think it is not possible)

Answer (score 0):

while Indexing you need to stop StandardTokenization.
OR
May be u need to consider writing new filter class (to merge the words) and include it filed Type definition in solrconfig file.